# Laravel 5: Auth/login destroying logged in user session

Tags: laravel, authentication

Quite possibly normal operating procedure to hit `auth/login` and display a login screen, however **if the user is logged in** would be better to re-direct to home(members-area).

What would be the best approach here?

Comment: what you tried?and what you can't do?
if you are using laravel 5.2 then run "php artisan make:auth" then your expected authentication will done

Comment: @ImtiazPabel if the user is logged in and then hits auth/login, user is logged out and login screen displayed

Answer (score 0):

yes you can if you use default authentication by using this `php artisan make:auth` then you can change your path as your wish in your **AuthController** you can change like this  `protected $redirectTo = '/home';`

Comment: I will setup a default laravel and test this, however i currently have redirectTo setup. However if the user is logged in and then hits auth/login, user is logged out and login screen displayed

Comment: @HarryBosh i cant understand what you telling can you make me clear

Comment: If(user == logged in) do not logout, redirect back to members area.